# Swift - can not write Array into Realm

Tags: swift, realm

I'm trying to write Array (with GPS coordinates), but now i even can not write Array with String.

My code:

```
import RealmSwift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let realm = try! Realm()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        save()
        
        render()
        
    }
    
        
    func save(){
        let joe = Person()
        joe.trackPoint = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
        print("Array write")
        realm.beginWrite()
        realm.add(joe)
        try! realm.commitWrite()
    }

    func render(){
        let people = realm.objects(Person.self)
        for person in people{
            print(person.trackPoint)
            print("Read ok")
        }
    }


}

class Person: Object{
    @objc dynamic var firstName: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var lastName: String = ""
    var trackPoint: [String] = []
}
```

And my console:

```
Array write
[]
Read ok
[]
Read ok
```

Array trackPoint don't write into Realm...

Please, help

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: Извините, я думал сайт на английском)